# The role of preposition

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

Hi i'm a english learner. Can you tell me what the difference is between
Calm and calm down 
Slow and slow down
Heat and heat up 
Cool and cool down 
Speed and speed up
Warm and warm up

I have no idea why people add a preposition after a verb when i think that the meaning of a verb is enough to express what i mean. 
I think the above questions seem to have the same role.
But i can't figure out what it is. 
Please explain about it 
Thank you so much :D

Comment: It signifies completion, or achieving the new, changed state.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of the preposition turns what would otherwise be a stand-alone part of speech (your examples are mostly adjectives) into a command.

For example, the word calm is an adjective that indicates a condition or a state of being.  If I command you to "calm down," I am telling you that you are not calm, and that you need to become calm.

Comment: No, you can say the room is cooling down, without there being any command.  In fact, how can you command a room to cool down?  The comment above by CJ Sheu is more accurate; these phrasal verbs mean a shift to a new and completely changed state.  The change is subtle; a person can calm his or her child or calm the child down; there's little difference except that "calm down" implies a more thorough change.

Comment: "Is cooling down" and "cool down" are not synonymous.  The questioner asked whether there is a difference, inter alia, between the word "calm" and the phrase "calm down."  Respondent Sheu would have been correct had the questioner cited the phrase "calmed down."  However, "calm down" does not in any way indicate an achieved state.  In that phrase, on its face, I see only room for a command.  As far as I can see, the questioner did not supply enough context to read more into the question.  I agree with all that you wrote beginning with "these phrasal verbs."